# Escaping command correctly for powershell.exe (launch command from CMD.exe)

Tags: powershell, cmd, escaping

How do I escape properly the below command? I need to run the powershell command from CMD because it's a stubpath value. The registry value for stubpath can't run powershell commands natively. The command is verified and works correctly. The problem is only to get it to run via `powershell.exe -command "..."`

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer | where-object { $_.Name -eq ("IPL" + ($env:COMPUTERNAME).Substring(1, 4)) }).SetDefaultPrinter()"
```

Right now it's breaking the line at "IPL" because of the double quotes. I think I have to escape the pipe has well.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `""IPL""` or `\"IPL\"`? You don't need to escape the `|` since it appears in between `""` anyway...

Comment: @aschipfl: When using PowerShell's _CLI_, only `\"IPL\"` works, not `""IPL""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might try this

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& { (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer | where-object { $_.Name -eq (\"IPL\" + ($env:COMPUTERNAME).Substring(1, 4)) }).SetDefaultPrinter() }"
```

otherwise, what i like to do to avoid escaping anything is encode the command into base64, then use powershell -encodedcommand, like this

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -EncodedCommand KABHAGUAdAAtAFcAbQBpAE8AYgBqAGUAYwB0ACAALQBDAGwAYQBzAHMAIABXAGkAbgAzADIAXwBQAHIAaQBuAHQAZQByACAAfAAgAHcAaABlAHIAZQAtAG8AYgBqAGUAYwB0ACAAewAgACQAXwAuAE4AYQBtAGUAIAAtAGUAcQAgACgAIgBJAFAATAAiACAAKwAgACgAJABlAG4AdgA6AEMATwBNAFAAVQBUAEUAUgBOAEEATQBFACkALgBTAHUAYgBzAHQAcgBpAG4AZwAoADEALAAgADQAKQApACAAfQApAC4AUwBlAHQARABlAGYAYQB1AGwAdABQAHIAaQBuAHQAZQByACgAKQA=
```

here is a link to info on how to encode your commands. this even works for full, multi-line scripts

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/timid/2014/03/26/powershell-encodedcommand-and-round-trips/

or you may be able to use this site to encode/decode

https://www.base64decode.org/

Answer (score 1):

Found it, I'll leave this here since it can be useful for other users:

Original powershell command :

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer | where-object { $_.Name -eq ("IPL" + ($env:COMPUTERNAME).Substring(1, 4)) }).SetDefaultPrinter()
```

To run from CMD.EXE, you have to escape the double quotes like this `\"IPL\"` instead of `"IPL"`

Working command:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer | where-object { $_.Name -eq (\"IPL\" + ($env:COMPUTERNAME).Substring(1, 4)) }).SetDefaultPrinter()"
```

Comment: Indeed; alternatively, you could have used `'IPL'`, which requires no escaping inside the overall `"..."` argument.